# Failing to program a third party NRF52832 board with nrf52DK through SWD connector after first time

Tags: swd, nrf52832

I'm trying to flash a simple blincky solution into my 3rd party board through a standard SWD programming header from the debug out port of my PCA10040 NRF52832 DK
with my Segger embedded studio IDE.

I've managed to upload the code for a single time but afterwards this simply doesn't work saying this: 
[image: Error message]

What could be the problem?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

One [application note](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/application-notes/an0062.pdf) that I found (just looking for generic SWD information) contains the following note:

> **Note**
>
> Keep in mind that if the debug pins are disabled, a debugger will no longer be able to connect to the EFM32. During development, it is therefore a good idea to make sure there is a delay between reset and disabling the pins (typically a few seconds). In that way the debugger has time to connect and halt the CPU before the pins are disabled. If you have disabled the debug pins and are unable to connect to your device, see Section 4.3 (p. 13) for instructions on how to perform the debug unlock sequence.

It sounds like you might have failed to do this in your code.

Comment: Uhh I don't get it I'm quite a simple user, can't understand why it works flawlessly with the DK but one time use with external chips? How do I make the third party chip preform as well as the DK for dev purposes?